# How is memory managed within threads?

Tags: multithreading, memory, thread-safety

If there is multiple threads going through a function which inside of it there is a for loop with variable assignment inside of it. How do variables values don't get messed up across multiple threads?

Comment: The memory doesn't get messed up if the *same* thread is in the middle of two executions of the same function (for example, if the function is recursive). Why would it get messed up if two threads were executing the function?

Comment: Did you mean to refer to function's local variables that are accessible only by that function's code, or global variables which are accessible by any other code in the entire program? If you mean local variables, then every thread receives a _copy_ of them. If you mean global variables, then multiple threads can mess up their values, unless, of course, you take special precaution.

Comment: The same way as when a single thread goes through the same function twice at the same time, such as through recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Each thread has a block of memory named "thread stack", of about 1MB for 32bits and 4Mb for 64 bitsr, where value types and references (pointers to the heap) that are parameters or intermediate results are stored; this space is not shared accross threads. The rest of things (ie: shared value types and references and the objects to which any references maybe pointing to) are stored in the heap, that is the rest of RAM memory and it is shared across all threads.

Values can be messed up across threads, for example in race conditions. If you try to update a 64 bits value from multiple threads with a 32 bits CPU, you could get an inconsistency, for preventing that you have many synchronization primitives in .NET like the `Interlock` and `Monitor` utilities for example. Also, non thread-safe objects like `List<>` can get messed up if using multiple threads without synchronization, and a simple integer incrementation can lost values if operation is not atomic.

You should do some read. I recommend you the book CLR via C# from Jeffrey Richter. Every .NET dev should read that book actually.